# How I can read '0b11001100' as one byte block not string in Python 3?

Tags: python

I need to read ('0b11001100') as 1 byte not string or chain of bytes. I already use python 3.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = int('0b11001100', 2)
print(b) # 204
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @LucaKiebel It's too elementary to add any explanation. You are over-thinking it.